# Copying Folder while Preserving Permissions/Ownership Error: operation not permitted

Tags: permissions, mysql, ownership

I am trying to copy a folder while preserving ownership. When I use the command:

```
sudo cp -R -p /var/lib/mysql /newpath
```

the files copy but the ownership changes (my username becomes the owner on the new files) and I get an error message saying that `cp: failed to preserve ownership for '/newpath/subdirectory' : Operation not permitted` for each subdirectory and file in the copied folder. Trying to switch back ownership on the copied files produces the same error (with chown in the place of cp).

```
sudo chown -R username:group /newpath
```

I am trying to copy a mysql data directory folder to my second hard drive in such a way that I can then use it as the database directory for the mysql server (username mysql) with webmin.

Comment: What is the filesystem type of the second hard drive? If ext2/3/4 does it have any extended attributes set (`lsattr /newpath`). How is it mounted?

Comment: File starts on ext4 and goes to fat32.

Answer (score 0):

FAT32 (or any FAT-type filesystem for that matter) does not support permissions. Any file copied to a FAT filesystem will appear with default owner/group/mode attributes, depending on how the filesystem was mounted.

If you need to preserve these attributes, use a different filesystem. Most (if not all) Unix filesystems (ext*, ReiserFS, btrfs and a bunch of others) supported by Linux will work, so will NTFS to an extent (not strictly a Unix filesystem but designed with a certain degree of Unix compatibility in mind).