# sudo cp --preserve=all not preserving ownership

Tags: permissions, cp, ownership

I am trying to copy data back onto an sd card with an ext2 type partition whilst preserving the ownership and permissions. I use the following command:

```
sudo cp -va --preserve=all 2nd/. /media/malapradej/AB6E-FC7F/
```

I get an error:

```
‘2nd/./dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@air.uk.co.bbc.android.mediaplayer-1@base.apk@classes.dex’ -> ‘/media/malapradej/AB6E-FC7F/./dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@air.uk.co.bbc.android.mediaplayer-1@base.apk@classes.dex’
cp: failed to preserve ownership for ‘/media/malapradej/AB6E-FC7F/./dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@air.uk.co.bbc.android.mediaplayer-1@base.apk@classes.dex’: Operation not permitted
```

According to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/461403/copying-folder-while-preserving-permissions-ownership-error-operation-not-permi) site this may be due to the extended attribute set of the sd card. The `lsattr /media/malapradej/AB6E-FC7F/` command shows:

```
lsattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device While reading flags on /media/malapradej/AB6E-FC7F/dalvik-cache
```

According to [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/324975/lsattr-inappropriate-ioctl-for-device-while-reading-flags) site I need to remount the sd card partition using:

```
sudo mount -o remount,user_xattr /media/malapradej/AB6E-FC7F/
```

But I get the same error and permissions and ownership is not retained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was all down to operator error. The file system I was trying to copy to was not ext2 in the end but FAT32. I did a `mount -l` and found:

```
/dev/sdb1 on /media/malapradej/AB6E-FC7F type vfat (rw,nosuid,nodev,uid=1000,gid=1000,shortname=mixed,dmask=0077,utf8=1,showexec,flush,user_xattr,uhelper=udisks2)
```